# Openlayers getFeatureById gives null

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geojson

I faced the following problem: I compiled a usefull map with own generated geojson data, that's work fine. Now I want to make summary box next to the map, the data for summary text is from the same geojson file with specific id (and fictitious coords) to reach them. So, I try to reach them with "getFeatureById", but it throws null...

Snippet from the geojson file (the first paragraph is data for summary text, the next paragraph is conventional geojson data):

```
{ "type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [
{"type": "Feature", "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates":  [0,0] }, "properties": { "id":"node/BP", "ossz_tervkoltseg":"9045.1", ... } },

{"type": "Feature", "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates":  [19.0908557,47.5269017] }, "properties": { "id":"node/8420278688", "ossz_tervkoltseg":"370.5", ... } },
...
```

My script:

```
const map = new ol.Map({
 view: new ol.View({ center: [2164846.200859313,5963803.432942492], zoom: 7.5}),
 layers: [ new ol.layer.Tile({ source: new ol.source.OSM() }) ],
 target: 'js-map' });

const prbGeoJSON = new ol.layer.VectorImage({
 source: new ol.source.Vector({ url: "./mli.geojson", format: new ol.format.GeoJSON() }),
 visible: true,
 title: "prbGeoJSON",
 style: function(feature, resolution){ ... } });

map.addLayer(prbGeoJSON); // it works fine so far
                        
map.once('postrender', function(event) {
 let feature = prbGeoJSON.getSource().getFeatureById("node/BP");        
 console.log(feature); // throw null...
});
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id should appear direcly in the feature object, not in its properties object

```
{"type": "Feature", "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates":  [0,0] }, "id": "node/BP", "properties": { "ossz_tervkoltseg":"9045.1", ... } },
```

If you need to use something from the properties object as a unique id for lookups you could set it when the features are added to the source

```
prbGeoJSON.getSource().on('addfeature', function(event) (
  event.feature.setId(event.feature.get('id');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! First of all, I fixed the geojson file as you advised. But I struggle the second part, with little success... I tried this:
`prbGeoJSON.getSource().on('addfeature', function(event) { event.feature.setId(event.feature.get('id')); });

map.once('postrender', function(event) {
    let feature = prbGeoJSON.getSource().getFeatureById("node/BP");        
    console.log(feature); // throw null... 
});`

Comment: It seems `getFeatureById("node/BP");` run first, not the `addfeature`...

Comment: The source url will not start to load until the layer is added to the map, the map may render several times before the load is complete.  Try `map.once('rendercomplete'` or `prbGeoJSON.getSource().once('featuresloadend'` instead of `postrender`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works:

`map.once('rendercomplete', function() {  
 let feature = prbGeoJSON.getSource().getFeatureById("node/BP");        
 console.log(feature); // heureka!
 });`